# Python Invalid syntax ':' when trying to select a list of rows to skip when importing from excel

Tags: excel, pandas

I'm trying to import some data from an excel file which has a very large footer.

When i put `skip_footer=[245:]` it tells me that : is invlaid syntax.

How can i cut out the footer from row `(0-indexed) 245` to the end of the footer?
I dont want to manually list it `[245, 246, 247 ...]` as that would take ages.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

skip_footer requires an integer. To skip from line 245 onward, unfortunately you need to know the number of lines in the file.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('your_file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
last_row = wb.max_row

pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', skip_footer=last_row-245)
```

In this case footer just refers to excess data at the end of the file you don't want to read, not the special Header / Footer feature in Excel, so the above will skip lines 245 onward.

Comment: Thanks, i thought that would remove 245 lines from the bottom.

Any idea why i cant specify range using : ?
Im doing it for skiprows too so [0:5] isnt allowed but [0,1,2,3,4,5] is.
Why is this?

Comment: That syntax is used to slice an existing list, not to create one. You can use skip_rows=range(0,6) to accomplish that.

Comment: I've realized that your comment about removing 245 lines is correct. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Excellent thank you, it all works fine now, great help :)